# How to get the model name from schema?

Tags: mongoose

How I can get the name of the model from schema like this way?
I have written a global plugin in mongoose to transform the model into CVS.

Now I have this solution but I don't feel it a good way.

```
let user = new User(newUser)
user.toCSV(user.collection.collectionName)
```

If there any possibility to be like that

```
let user = new User(newUser)
user.toCSV()
```

the code of the plugin.

```
module.exports = function toCSV(schema, options) {

  schema.methods.toCSV = function toCSV(modelName) {
    var fields = Object.keys(schema.obj);
    let model = mongoose.model(modelName, schema);

    model.find({}, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return {
          code: err.code,
          message: err.message,
          data: {}
        };
      } else {
        let csv
        try {
          var fields = Object.keys(schema.obj);
          csv = json2csv(data, {
            fields
          });
        } catch (err) {
          return {
            code: err.code,
            message: err.message,
            data: {}
          };

        }
        const dateTime = moment().format('YYYYMMDDhhmmss');
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../..", "exports", "csv-" + dateTime + ".csv")
        fs.writeFile(filePath, csv, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return {
              code: err.code,
              message: err.message,
              data: {}
            };

          } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
              fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
               // delete this file after 1 hour
              // Time in milliseconds to remove the CSV from server
              // so you will have the time to upload it to cloud
            }, process.env.TIMER_TO_REMOVE_CSV)
            "/exports/csv-" + dateTime + ".csv";
            return {
               code: 200,
              message: "complete",
              data: {
                filePath: "/exports/csv-" + dateTime + ".csv"
              }
            };
          }
        });

      }
    })
  };

}
```

1- How I can get the name from schema or if I can use mongoose?
2- How I can change this inside the plugin?

```
 let model = mongoose.model(modelName, schema);

    model.find({},(err,result)=>{});
```

**Or if there any way to run this model.find({}) by the schema because that will solve both of these problems, I don't know so much about mongo because I'm new in it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `modelName` try `this.collection.collectionName`